# type for material UI icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

I have a component that looks like this:

```
type IconButtonProps = { text: string ; onClick: () => void, icon: any};

export const IconButton: FunctionComponent<IconButtonProps> = ({
  text,
  onClick,
  icon,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button className={classes.button} 
    onClick={onClick}
   >
     {' '}
    {icon}
     {text}
   </Button>
  );
};
```

and is called like this:

```
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

<IconButton text={'Search'} icon={<SearchIcon />} onClick={()=>SearchUsers()}></IconButton>
```

In the props, I am using `any` as the icon's type. What's the correct type to use? I want to avoid using any type.

Comment: Where are you importing the SearchIcon from ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan 
SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 25):

Maybe `import { SvgIconComponent } from "@material-ui/icons";`

Comment: that's a component, not a type?

Comment: it is a type https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9bd4277ecd660ebe2fd4cb08960f58e98ddb6d43/packages/material-ui-icons/scripts/create-typings.js#L24

Comment: thanks! this worked for me. for MUI V5, it's 

`import { SvgIconComponent } from "@mui/icons-material";`